# Average Array for int values in a 2D String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int

I am having a bit of trouble with my program which holds student names and grades in a 2D string array. Basically, I have a second (1D) array that will hold average grade for each student.

code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a 2D array for names, and their grades, and an array for average grades
        string[,] studentGrades = new string[5, 8];
        int[] average = new int[studentGrades.GetLength(0)];

        // Set student names/grades manually
        studentGrades[0, 0] = "Steve";
        studentGrades[0, 1] = "69";
        studentGrades[0, 2] = "80";
        studentGrades[0, 3] = "66";
        studentGrades[0, 4] = "75";
        studentGrades[0, 5] = "90";
        studentGrades[0, 6] = "69";
        studentGrades[0, 7] = "98";

        studentGrades[1, 0] = "Bob";
        studentGrades[1, 1] = "73";
        studentGrades[1, 2] = "67";
        studentGrades[1, 3] = "65";
        studentGrades[1, 4] = "91";
        studentGrades[1, 5] = "48";
        studentGrades[1, 6] = "33";
        studentGrades[1, 7] = "94";

        studentGrades[2, 0] = "Lewis";
        studentGrades[2, 1] = "67";
        studentGrades[2, 2] = "80";
        studentGrades[2, 3] = "66";
        studentGrades[2, 4] = "75";
        studentGrades[2, 5] = "90";
        studentGrades[2, 6] = "69";
        studentGrades[2, 7] = "63";

        studentGrades[3, 0] = "Sara";
        studentGrades[3, 1] = "55";
        studentGrades[3, 2] = "58";
        studentGrades[3, 3] = "63";
        studentGrades[3, 4] = "70";
        studentGrades[3, 5] = "55";
        studentGrades[3, 6] = "55";
        studentGrades[3, 7] = "76";

        studentGrades[4, 0] = "Xavier";
        studentGrades[4, 1] = "22";
        studentGrades[4, 2] = "27";
        studentGrades[4, 3] = "25";
        studentGrades[4, 4] = "19";
        studentGrades[4, 5] = "42";
        studentGrades[4, 6] = "18";
        studentGrades[4, 7] = "32";

        // Loop the array dimensions and output/format output the names/grades
        for (int name = 0; name < studentGrades.GetLength(0); name++)
        {
            for (int grade = 0; grade < studentGrades.GetLength(1); grade++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(studentGrades[name, grade]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < studentGrades.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < studentGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                average[j] += int.Parse(studentGrades[i, j]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I get an un-handled exception in regards to the input string not being in the correct format where the average is set.

All help is appreciated!

### Update

I've reviewed the solutions of code so far below, and I'm still having issues with getting the grade average to work as intended. I have 5 students with 7 grades. I want the program to output the average of each persons grades below their column.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a 2D array for names, and their grades, and an array for average grades
        string[,] studentGrades = new string[5, 8];
        int[] average = new int[studentGrades.GetLength(1)];

        // Set student names/grades manually
        //As done above, excluded for brevity reasons


        // Loop the array dimensions and output/format output the names/grades
        for (int grade = 0; grade < studentGrades.GetLength(1); grade++)
        {
            for (int name = 0; name < studentGrades.GetLength(0); name++)
            {
                // Composite formatting is used to align names/grades in grid -- specifically the alignment component.
                // Making the value higher (more neg) will increase spacing between elements
                // Positive number would right align elements instead
                Console.Write("{0, -15}", studentGrades[name, grade]);
            }
            // Moves each printed grade to a new line
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < studentGrades.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < studentGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                average[j] += int.Parse(studentGrades[i, j]);
            }

            average[i] /= studentGrades.GetLength(1) - 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= average.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0, -15}", i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");


    }
```

### Update 2

It seems that the average array is not being properly populated. It seems to just print out 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 if I remove the average division. Furthermore, if I change averages' length to 5 -- or the length of the amount of names since there will only be 5 values, it breaks. This is likely because it's trying to add 7 items to a 5 item array.

Comment: I'd consider changing the type to a Dictionary<string, List<int>> instead. Should be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this part of code:

```
// Store the average as a double array, otherwise you can't have averages with decimal values.
double[] average = new double[studentGrades.GetLength(0)];

for (int i = 0; i < studentGrades.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    // Start from j = 1, as j = 0 would get a name instead of a grade.
    for (int j = 1; j < studentGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // Here use average[i] instead of average[j], because you want
        // the average grade for each student.
        average[i] += int.Parse(studentGrades[i, j]);
    }

    // Finish calculating the average.
    // GetLength(0) - 1 because the first item is a name, not a grade.
    average[i] /= studentGrades.GetLength(1) - 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i <= average.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
{
    // Show at most 2 decimal digits.
    Console.Write("{0, -15:#.##}", average[i]);
}
```

Comment: I've updated the post with more info, could you please take a look at that, I'm not getting the results I expected.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can find the full working example here: http://gist.github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/4674d227756ab1c42681

Answer (score 2):

Every `studentGrages[*, 0]` element is not integer so you can't parse it to `int`

Skip the first elements

```
 for (int i = 0; i < studentGrades.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
       for (int j = 1; j < studentGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
       {
                average[j] += int.Parse(studentGrades[i, j]);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to include the string of the names (on the 0 index) with the average. e.g `int.Parse("Steve")` which is causing the exception, just skip on the first element on each colum.

```
for (int j = 1; j < studentGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have rightly pointed out, you need to change the `0` to a `1` in the following line:

```
for (int j = 1; j < studentGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
```

Otherwise you're going to try to parse the name as an integer.

Also you need to change the index on average inside the loop to `i` rather than `j`.

```
average[i] += int.Parse(studentGrades[i, j]);
```

The other issue that you're going to have is that you're using integer mathematics - so when you do something like `7 / 2` you get an answer of `3` and not `3.5`.

If I were you, and you don't want to change your data structure, I would do it this way:

```
var results =
    studentGrades
        .Cast<string>()
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .GroupBy(xn =>  xn.n / studentGrades.GetLength(1), xn => xn.x)
        .Select(xs => new
        {
            student = xs.First(),
            average = xs.Skip(1).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Average(),
        })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

Alternatively, I would suggest that you change your data structure to this:

```
var studentGrades = new []
{
    new { student = "Steve", grades = new [] { 69, 80, 66, 75, 90, 69, 98, } },
    new { student = "Bob", grades = new [] { 73, 67, 65, 91, 48, 33, 94, } },
    new { student = "Lewis", grades = new [] { 67, 80, 66, 75, 90, 69, 63, } },
    new { student = "Sara", grades = new [] { 55, 58, 63, 70, 55, 55, 76, } },
    new { student = "Xavier", grades = new [] { 22, 27, 25, 19, 42, 18, 32, } },
};
```

Then this should work for you:

```
var results =
    studentGrades
        .Select(sg => new
        {
            sg.student,
            average = sg.grades.Average(),
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I have changed that line in the update code, but it doesn't seem to even be working correctly in the sense of population of the array. It fills the array with 0 - 7. Additionally, I'd want 5, as there are 5 people, but this obviously gives an out-of-bounds  error.

Comment: @ryderd - You also have an issue with your index on `average`. I've edited my answer to show you what the issue is.